# no such file or directory (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install a solver (SCIP) with cygwin. After unpacking the folder consists of another 5 folders. The manual says I have to go in folder A and use `make`. Here, I get the message that one file was not found:

> zimpl/bool.h: No such file or directory

This file is in folder B in the path zimpl/src/bool.h. How can I link this file from folder B that cygwin can use it while using `make` in folder A?

The support says:

> Blockquote The error you postet looks like your zimpl softlink is incorrect. If you use a relative path, make sure that it is relative to the position where
>   the link is created. Most softlinks are created directly in the lib
>   directory, the zimpl softlink, however, is in a subdirectory of the lib
>   directory, so you have to go up two directories to get to the main SCIP
>   directory.

However I am not sure how to check the softlinks.

Thanks!

Comment: without looking the code it is impossible to say. Due to the licence `http://scip.zib.de/academic.txt` I suggest you to ask the Authors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my post on some information. Maybe they help you to help me with my issue?

Comment: It seems `http://zimpl.zib.de/` is a pre requisite for SCIP. So you need to install ZIMPL before installing SCIP.

Comment: No, the Scip Optimization Suite contains both scip and zimpl. You just have to install scip and it automatically installs all necessary components such as zimpl. I already installed the Scip Opt Suite on my Macbook without errors. However, on Windows it is more problematic...